# MVC4 Application Generates Empty <body> with ambiguous tag in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have experienced 2 years in working with Microsoft MVC but today saw a strange tag and browser shows nothing on page load. That is after `<html>` and before `<head>` tags:

```
<object type="{0C55C096-0F1D-4F28-AAA2-85EF591126E7}" cotype="cs" id="cosymantecbfw" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; display: block;"></object>
```

> While, The master layout is full of partial/static views.

The `<body>` tag is completely null! **Result viewed in Google Chrome**.

**Edit:** Alien Tag Produced by Norton(Symantec) in Google Chrome according to [this page](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/423318/alien-object-and-js-in-chrome-inspect-element).

Comment: "The master layout is full of partial/static views." did you check them?

Comment: ya, full of elements. I searched around this and found this : http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/javascript-dhtml-ajax/threads/423318/alien-object-and-js-in-chrome-inspect-element truely I have Norton Internet Security but Why no elements in body?

Comment: Norton is the second major Security product in all over the world. Why? See PCWorld Magazine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not related to loading partial views and MVC works fine.

JavaScript parts of page cause the problem. When we use our own scripts to employ called libraries to render elements, features and etc..., we have 2 choices to add scripts :

1. Add by calling script file
2. Add by writing scripts inside related page

> I have used both of 2 above concepts in my pages. I solved it by using
>   second solution by collecting all of scripts in a file.

**And the ambiguous tag generated by Norton Internet Security In Google Chrome not in another Browsers.**